# Align field to right in grid layout in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want my application to align two field, one to left and other to extreme left of the screen. For that i am using GridLayoutManager class. Here is my code

```
GridFieldManager gridFieldManager = new GridFieldManager(2,2, GridFieldManager.PREFERRED_SIZE_WITH_MAXIMUM); 

gridFieldManager.add(new ButtonField("Button One"), Field.FIELD_HCENTER);  
gridFieldManager.add(new ButtonField("Button Two"), Field.FIELD_RIGHT);  

gridFieldManager.add(new ButtonField("HC", Field.FIELD_HCENTER)); 
gridFieldManager.add(new ButtonField("RT", Field.FIELD_RIGHT));

add(gridFieldManager);
```

And, here is my output in simulator

[image]

Can anyone please help me to align the Button Two to the extreme right of the screen ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10082358/396949) for alternative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this following class.

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager;

public class HFMLeftFieldRightField extends HorizontalFieldManager {

 private Field leftField;
 private Field rightField;

 private final static int TOP_MARGIN = 0;
 private final static int LEFT_MARGIN = 30;

 public HFMLeftFieldRightField() {
  super(USE_ALL_WIDTH);
 }

 public HFMLeftFieldRightField(boolean isQatari) {
  super(USE_ALL_WIDTH | Field.FIELD_LEFT);
 }

 public void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {

  super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
  int width = getWidth();

  if (rightField != null) {
   int x = width - rightField.getWidth() - LEFT_MARGIN;
   int y = TOP_MARGIN;
   setPositionChild(rightField, x, y);
  }
  if (leftField != null) {
   int y = TOP_MARGIN+rightField.getHeight()/5;
   int x = LEFT_MARGIN;
   setPositionChild(leftField, 0, y);
  }

  setExtent(maxWidth, rightField.getHeight() + TOP_MARGIN * 2);
 }

 public void setLeftButton(Field leftField) {
  this.leftField = leftField;
super.add(leftField);
 }

 public void setRightButton(Field rightField) {
  this.rightField = rightField;
  super.add(rightField);
 }


}
```

And add field this way.

```
HFMLeftFieldRightField hfm = new HFMLeftFieldRightField();
hfm.setLeftButton(new EditField("Left"));
hfm.setRightButton(new EditField("Right"));
add(hfm);
```

More detail http://keraisureshvblackberry.blogspot.in/2012/02/there-are-very-common-there-there-are.html

Hope helpfull..

Comment: The sublayout() here is redundant. You can get away with alignment flags only.

Comment: @MrVincenzo Using a HFM means you want a specific horizontal layout, and it is not possible to have a general purpose horizontal layout algorithm that avoids overlap while also satisfying horizontal constraints like LEFT, RIGHT, CENTER on each subfield. The solution for HorizontalFieldManager is to ignore horizontal alignment flags, and only use vertical flags.  To get the behavior the OP wants, a custom manager is needed.

Comment: @MichaelDonohue Instead of adding `HorizontalFieldManager`, position calculations and many redundant lines of code, one could continue using the `GridFieldManager` and get away with two additional function calls `setColumnProperty(0, GridFieldManager.AUTO_SIZE, 0)` and `setColumnProperty(1, GridFieldManager.AUTO_SIZE, 0)` and possibly changing the existing field's alignment flags to achieve the desired result (with addition of only two lines of code).

Comment: @MichaelDonohue forgot to mention that the `GridFieldManager` style should be changed to `GridFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH` as well.

Comment: @MichaelDonohue I've implemented the things I talked about in my answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10082358/396949.

Answer (score 3):

Basically it's all a matter of alignment flags and grid's column properties.

Changing the `GridFieldManager` style to `Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH` and setting column properties to `GridFieldManager.AUTO_SIZE` makes all the available space to be divided evently among the two columns.

```
gridFieldManager.setColumnProperty(0, GridFieldManager.AUTO_SIZE, 0);
gridFieldManager.setColumnProperty(1, GridFieldManager.AUTO_SIZE, 0);
```

---

The following code snippet

```
GridFieldManager gridFieldManager = new GridFieldManager(2,2, Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH); 
gridFieldManager.setColumnProperty(0, GridFieldManager.AUTO_SIZE, 0);
gridFieldManager.setColumnProperty(1, GridFieldManager.AUTO_SIZE, 0);

gridFieldManager.add(new ButtonField("Button One"), Field.FIELD_LEFT);  
gridFieldManager.add(new ButtonField("Button Two"), Field.FIELD_RIGHT);  
gridFieldManager.add(new ButtonField("HC"), Field.FIELD_LEFT); 
gridFieldManager.add(new ButtonField("RT"), Field.FIELD_RIGHT);

add(gridFieldManager);
```

produces

[image]

---

This slightly modified code snippet

```
GridFieldManager gridFieldManager = new GridFieldManager(1,2, Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH); 
gridFieldManager.setColumnProperty(0, GridFieldManager.AUTO_SIZE, 0);
gridFieldManager.setColumnProperty(1, GridFieldManager.AUTO_SIZE, 0);

VerticalFieldManager vfmLeft = new VerticalFieldManager();
vfmLeft.add(new ButtonField("Button One", Field.FIELD_HCENTER));  
vfmLeft.add(new ButtonField("HC", Field.FIELD_HCENTER)); 
gridFieldManager.add(vfmLeft, Field.FIELD_LEFT);  

VerticalFieldManager vfmRight = new VerticalFieldManager();
vfmRight.add(new ButtonField("Button Two", Field.FIELD_HCENTER));  
vfmRight.add(new ButtonField("RT", Field.FIELD_HCENTER));
gridFieldManager.add(vfmRight, Field.FIELD_RIGHT);  

add(gridFieldManager);
```

produces

[image]

---

Finally, to illustrate what I said previously about the available space being divided evently among the two columns, the following code snippet

```
GridFieldManager gridFieldManager = new GridFieldManager(1,2, Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH | Manager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT); 
gridFieldManager.setColumnProperty(0, GridFieldManager.AUTO_SIZE, 0);
gridFieldManager.setColumnProperty(1, GridFieldManager.AUTO_SIZE, 0);
gridFieldManager.setRowProperty(0, GridFieldManager.AUTO_SIZE, 0);

VerticalFieldManager vfmLeft = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH | Manager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT);
vfmLeft.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.CYAN));
gridFieldManager.add(vfmLeft);  

VerticalFieldManager vfmRight = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH | Manager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT);
vfmRight.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.GRAY));
gridFieldManager.add(vfmRight);  

add(gridFieldManager);
```

produces two columns of equal size.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you should use **JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager** instead of GridFieldManager. JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager is not a standard manager included in BlackBerry SDK, but a member of a set of UI components released by RIM later to help developers build more rich UI Interfaces. You have to download the code from [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276), add it to your proyect and then include the following line:

```
JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager justifiedManager = new JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager(buttonOne, buttonTwo, false, USE_ALL_WIDTH );
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the style parameter of your gridFieldManager constructor to 
GridFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH

It should be like this

```
GridFieldManager gridFieldManager = new GridFieldManager(2,2,GridFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH );
```

Comment: Then override the sublayout of gridfieldManager and set child position